# How to import multiple users from CSV to SharePoint list User field?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I am trying to import a CSV to a SharePoint list which is working for all the field types I need except where the field is Person or Group and it allows multiple selections. I have a Person field where multiple selections are not allowed:

```
$listItem["SinglePersonField"] = $web.EnsureUser($csvRow.AssignedTo)
```

The CSV holds the user's email address

I can format the CSV so the multiple users are in one column or several. I tried building a string but it's not working unless I use EnsureUser. Is there a way to ensure multiple users and append them to the multi person field?

Comment: You’ll need to use a foreach structure and ensure each of the users, and put each of them in an array. Then assign the array to the value of your field.

Answer (score 0):

You can put multiple users in a column and use semicolon to spit users. Then ensure each of the users.You could check this article for more:

http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/07/import-from-csv-to-sharepoint-list-with-people-picker.html